# Cosmos DB create a temp table using a select statement

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In cosmos db, if I do something like this,

```
select "a", "b"
```

I get something similar to a table with one row with two columns having values a and b. Now, can I do something where I can add another row with values "c" and "d" into this same table, so something like:

```
select ("a","b"),("c","d")
```

Ofc, this wouldn't work, but since Cosmos doesn't have the union statement, I was wondering how such a query would work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good way to do this here:

```
SELECT VALUE [
        {unit: 'ng', name: 'nanogram', multiplier: 0.000000001, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'µg', name: 'microgram', multiplier: 0.000001, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'mg', name: 'milligram', multiplier: 0.001, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'g', name: 'gram', multiplier: 1, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'kg', name: 'kilogram', multiplier: 1000, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'Mg', name: 'megagram', multiplier: 1000000, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'Gg', name: 'gigagram', multiplier: 1000000000, baseUnit: 'gram'},
        {unit: 'nJ', name: 'nanojoule', multiplier: 0.000000001, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'µJ', name: 'microjoule', multiplier: 0.000001, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'mJ', name: 'millijoule', multiplier: 0.001, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'J', name: 'joule', multiplier: 1, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'kJ', name: 'kilojoule', multiplier: 1000, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'MJ', name: 'megajoule', multiplier: 1000000, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'GJ', name: 'gigajoule', multiplier: 1000000000, baseUnit: 'joule'},
        {unit: 'cal', name: 'calorie', multiplier: 1, baseUnit: 'calorie'},
        {unit: 'kcal', name: 'Calorie', multiplier: 1000, baseUnit: 'calorie'},
        {unit: 'IU', name: 'International units'}
    ]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery